# Issue with mobile website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mobile, web

I have a mobile version of my site that I have an issue with. My main site is (let's say) `domain.com` and my mobile site is (let's say) `m.dom.com`

I have common js/css and images I use for both and I don't want to duplicate the files to either both sites. if I need to update I don't want to copy over and over or just forget to upload the other file.

My mobile site is setup in a sub folder of my main site `/mobile` so i have domain.com/mobile is the same as `m.dom.com`

is there an easy way to not duplicate/copy over and over the images/js?

Comment: you have a share or dedicated?

Comment: ;) no problem i assume it was shared hosting

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create symblink from the parent folder:

Using ssh or plesk or cpanel:

```
shell:/path/to/www/mobile> ln -s ../js/
shell:/path/to/www/mobile> ln -s ../images/
shell:/path/to/www/mobile> ln -s ../css/
etc...
```

This will create a symbolic link from your main site so you only have to uploads the file from your main site and automatically the mobile will get updated.

So when you access the `/js/file.js` in your mobile site it will look for the symblink which is the main `/js/file.js`.

Also I would recommend to use this rule (from your main site - .htaccess) in case the `/mobile/` is accessed from a bot or a user.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mobile/?$ http://m.dom.com/ [R=301]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use CSS to modify the content so you that you don't have to create the same thing twice

Comment: that is good but it does not help improve performance for slow network. if your main html file is 100k that can be slow for to load and since you modify the css the html file still unchanged.